# OpenSSL keys generate only partial keys

Tags: php, php-openssl

My PHP script is generating only partial keys, they are about 50% of what they should be and are missing the closing headers, here is how I generate the keys:

```
    private function GetKeyPair(&$private_key, &$public_key){


            //write your configurations :D
            $configargs = array(
              "config" => "C:/xampp/php/extras/openssl/openssl.cnf",
              'private_key_bits'=> 2048,
              'digest_alg' => 'sha256',
              //'default_md' => "sha256",
            );

        // Create the keypair
        $res=openssl_pkey_new($configargs);

        // Get private key
        openssl_pkey_export($res, $private_key,NULL,$configargs);               
        
        // Get public key details
        $private_key_details = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);

        $public_key=$private_key_details["key"];

        return true;
    }
```

The `$private_key` I obtain looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQC5Q2uupK5kjw9G
7mFFq8AxbTCYc91ZsV//oDqKE7+xOMkfZIXIAROC3HZm6DO2lMDkNSLhWIOyHvDS
+rrLK9DM4lQafmUmiVRkdaDCEcKzd6gKQuatutmVRuqpFTLO6HAN15KOEOi48R72
KeNn5h2wML/ut3Q7W6T1/jNJPViBVMDD
```

While the `$public_key` is:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuUNrrqSuZI8PRu5hRavA
MW0wmHPdWbFf/6A6ihO/sTjJH2SFyAETgtx2ZugztpTA5DUi4ViDsh7w0vq6yyvQ
zOJUGn5lJolUZHWgwhHCs3eoCkLmrbrZlUbqqRUyzuhwDdeSjhDouPEe9injZ+Yd
sDC/7rd0O1uk9f4zST1YgVTAw/r9sbijP
```

I could not find anything in my config file pointing that the keys will be truncated, and these values are before being snet ot the database, if I inspect the variables they are also truncated.